# How do I use sprintf to zero fill to a variable length in Perl?

Tags: perl, printf, zerofill

I want to use Perl's [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) to zerofill a variable.

```
sprintf("%08d", $var);
```

But I want to dynamically determine how many digits to zerofill.

How do I replace the "8" in `sprintf("%08d", $var)` with a variable called `$zerofill`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first argument to [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) is just a string:

```
 my $zerofill = 9;
 my $number = 1000;
 my $filled = sprintf "%0${zerofill}d", $number;
```

Notice the braces to set apart the variable name from the rest of the string.

We have this particular problem as a slightly clever exercise in [Learning Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520113) to remind people that strings are just strings. :)

However, as [mobrule points out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471298/how-do-i-use-sprintf-to-zero-fill-to-a-variable-length-in-perl/2471369#2471369), sprintf has many features to give you this sort of flexibility. The documentation for such a seemingly simple function is quite long and there are a lot of goodies in it.

Answer (score 15):

`sprintf` and `printf` support the `*` notation (this has worked since at least 5.8):

---

```
printf "%0*d", 9, 12345;

000012345
```

---

```
printf '$%*.*f', 8, 2, 456.78;

$  456.78
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to do something slightly different: zero pad a floating point value and get an exact length.

In my case I need exactly 12 bytes including the decimal point. It is slightly trickier than what you have above. Here it is in case anyone needs this:

Say $inputVal is a string passed in from somewhere with a value like *1001.1*. Note that it should be less than 12 characters for this to work reliably

```
 # This will give us extra zeros, but the string may be too long
 my $floatVal = sprintf('%*.*f', 12, 12, $inputValue);

 # This will remove any extra zeros
 $result = substr($floatVal, 0, 12);
```