# Appending 0 before binary number based on a value in a variable

Tags: perl

I am writing a code where I need to convert some forms of no to binary no for some processing. I want the size of binary no based on the value stored in a variable for which I need to append some leading zeroes.
for example, say there is variable $size =15
Now I want to convert a no from decimal to 15 bit binary

I know how to manually give the count
for ex -
if we want 8 digit binary no from some decimal no then we will use-

```
    $data_binary = sprintf( "%08b", $initial_data );
```

But how to specify the size of binary no if the size is stored in some variable??

For example=

```
    If size =10
    decimal no =12
    required binary no = 0000001100
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use sprintf to zero fill to a variable length in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471298/how-do-i-use-sprintf-to-zero-fill-to-a-variable-length-in-perl)

Answer (score 1):

See [`perldoc -f sprintf`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html#(minimum)-width):

```
$data_binary = sprintf( "%0*b", $size, $initial_data );
```

For instance,

```
printf "%0*b\n", 10, 12
```

prints

```
0000001100
```

If the binary representation of your number contains more than `$size` bits, it won't be truncated. Depending on your use case, you might want to add a `substr` afterward (but I'd be surprised if you'd actually need to do that).

Comment: Just found out that this is a duplicate; gonna delete this answer.

Comment: Well, I definitely don't like the accepted answer, so I'm undeleting this answer, which I think provides a much better way to achieve what OP wants.

Answer (score -1):

You can use one sprintf to generate format string for another sprintf.
[ There is more than one way to do it ]

```
use strict; use warnings;
my $binary_length = 10;
my $initial_data = 12;

my $format = sprintf('%%0%db', int($binary_length));
my $data_binary = sprintf( $format, $initial_data );
print $data_binary,"\n";
```

Comment: That's unnecessarily complicated. Also, why are you converting `$binary_length` to a float first?

Comment: @melpomene 1. It is "general" (any programming language) way.  It may be easily improved for perl. 2.  `int($binary_length)` - I prefer such extra safeguards.

Comment: `int($binary_length)` is not a safeguard. It unnecessarily converts the number to a float.

Comment: This solution is not general: It only works in programming languages where `printf` can take a runtime string. A truly general solution would be `sprintf '%0*b', $binary_length, $initial_data`, which is also the shortest / simplest solution (except `%b` is non-standard).

Comment: @melpomene You can provide better answer (in your opinion).

Comment: @AnFi This question is a duplicate. The better answers on the [dup target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471298/how-do-i-use-sprintf-to-zero-fill-to-a-variable-length-in-perl).